# after successful php upload file not found

Tags: php

I'm having inconsistent results with the php file upload script below.

After each upload attempt the $statusMsg tells me the upload was completed successfully but when I look for the file in the expected directory nothing is found about 25% of the time.

phpinfo() has no entry for upload_tmp_dir. Could that be the problem even if it works most of the time? If so, how might I go about editing the phprc file if that's the solution?

```
    $targetDir = $_POST['path'];
    $fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
    $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
        // Allow certain file formats
        $allowTypes = array('jpg','jpeg');
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
            // Upload file to server
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
                $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully to ".$targetFilePath ;
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }else{
            $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG files are allowed to upload.';
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
    }
```

Here's what var_dump($_FILES) shows:

array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(13) "worldMap4.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpD9lY4v" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(3247134) } }

And $statusMsg shows:
The file worldMap4.jpg has been uploaded successfully to ../LIBRARY/clientID/images/worldMap4.jpg

Comment: uploads can fail, you need to check for it: [file-upload.errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: That's just the problem. I just tried uploading the same file 10 times, each time file-upload error = 0. However 3 of those times the file could not be found in the target dir. (Yes, I did  delete the file before each try and cleared the cache before each look)

Comment: Is there is maybe a permissions issue

Comment: This probably isn't relevant, but if you're uploading the same file all the time, you could use `clearstatcache()` at the start of the script.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I've added clearstatcache() but see no change

Comment: Im working with macOS Catalina

Comment: permissions on the target dir are "write"

Comment: I've now created an entry for upload_tmp_dir in phpInfo and the behaviour has improved considerably. So now the uploaded file shows up in the target dir about 4 out of 5 attempts. That's better but unsatisfactory